# Tomcat application doesn't deploy

Tags: windows, tomcat

An application that was working perfectly well stopped working after a restart of the Tomcat service.

There are no errors in the Tomcat log and the last line just says that the application is deploying and it seems to be stuck there.

Comment: the first question comming to my mind: some changes in other systems this one might be depending upon? (DBS,...). If not, debugging might help to reveal the place where it gets stuck

Comment: I tried starting tomcat manually "catalina start" but it also looks like it is stuck on deploying the directory

Comment: ok, another shots to darkness :) did you check permissions (as suggested in the answer)? did you check there is enough space on the hdd?

Comment: one more thing, once you remove your app, does tomcat start up and serve some default content?

Comment: hi once I removed all the webapps tomcat started successfully, the issue was indeed because of another system the application depended upon.

Comment: good news then! :) happy you got it resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a file is in use by the OS, or there's a permissions issue blocking the redeploy. Try deleting the war and folder from the webapps directory manually and then deploy.

Comment: A machine restart doesn't help. Also tried removing the webapp directories and putting them back. The issue remains.

Comment: can you post the contents of your catalina.out?